# Get the auto increment id of replicated record in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to achieve something very simple. I have a datatable and I am allowing users to create clone of a record and open it in edit mode.

My controller is as below.

```
public function clone($id)
{
    $inventory=Inventory::find($id)->replicate();
    $inventory->save();
    return $this->edit($inventory->$id);
}
```

I was hoping to get the *id* of the cloned record from `$inventory->$id`, but it still gives me old *id*. But when I check in DB its generating a new *id*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have typo in $id

```
return $this->edit($inventory->id);
```

this should help